# How to call upon classes in php

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

Essentially I am new to OOP programming and php, html, css and mysqli. I am programming quite an advanced website for my coursework which is a large jump. I was just wondering how you call on a class within a page, e.g

```
public function appointment_data($book_date, $book_time, $stu_id, $stf_id, $lab_id, $reason){
            $strTime = strval($book_time);
            $sqlTime;
            if ($book_time < 1000) {
                $sqlTime = "0" . subStr($strTime, 0, 1) . ":" . subStr($strTime, 1, 2);
            } else {
                $sqlTime = subStr($strTime, 0, 2) . ":" . subStr($strTime, 2, 2);                
            }
            $result = $this->_db->query("INSERT INTO appointments 
         (Appt_Date, Appt_Time, Student_Id, Teacher_Id, Location_Id, Reason) VALUES 
         ('$book_date', '$sqlTime', $stu_id, $stf_id, $lab_id, '$reason')");
            }
```

This is one of my functions, but im having trouble calling it up and using it. All the logic should be right?

Answer (score 2):

If this, for instance, is part of a class called Appointment, you call it like this:

```
// Instantiate an object of class Appointment
$appointment_obj = new Appointment();  

// Call method appointment_data()
$appointment_obj->appointment_data($date, $time, $stu_id, $stf_id, $lab_id, $reason);
```

Just to make it more complete:

If you do not have and cannot instantiate an object instance, you can also call the method statically if you add `static` to the function declaration:

```
public static function appointment_data($book_date, $book_time, $stu_id, $stf_id, $lab_id, $reason){
```

You can then call it like this:

```
Appointment::appointment_data($date, $time, $stu_id, $stf_id, $lab_id, $reason);
```

However, you cannot do that if you leave the function like it is, as it references `$this`, which represents the current object and is NOT available in static functions.

Comment: Thanks so much thats really helped. Sorry if my question wasnt very clear, im new to all of this.

Comment: Glad it helped! Feel free to ask more questions as they arise.

Comment: Yea I had been, but the problem is I have to essentially learn html, css, php and mysqli simultaneously in a short period of time. the basics of html and css was quite easy to learn for me, but I cannot get my head around php!

Comment: @StevanSoupbal wish you luck, and if this is the right answer accept it,